# Is there a bijection between R and (-infinity, 3)? What would be the function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

I need to find a bijective function between the sets R and (-infinity, 3). How would I come to that?

Comment: $$ f(x)=3-e^x$$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You've gotten an answer. If it satisfies you please accept it (the check mark) and upvote it. In the future, when you ask a question you should show some work of your own - what you tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can build bijections like that using bijections like these:

- $\exp:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$.
- $\log:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
- $\tan:(-\pi/2, \pi/2)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
- $\tan^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow  (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$

These four functions form bijections between $\mathbb{R}$ and intervals that are finite on one end or both ends.  Using these functions, along with addition and multiplication by constants, you can make a bijection between intervals of any size.

In your case, note that

- $f_1(x) = \exp(x)$ sends $\mathbb{R}$ bijectively to $(0,\infty)$.
- Negating the expression, $f_2(x) = -\exp(x)$ sends $\mathbb{R}$ bijectively to $(-\infty, 0)$.
- Adding three to move the function over, $f_3(x) = 3 - \exp(x)$ sends $\mathbb{R}$ bijectively to $(-\infty, 3)$, as required.

$$f(x) = 3 - \exp{x}$$